# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I had my Anaconda working but when I tried to install keras-gpu using conda command, it ended with a permission error. After even typing conda in my terminal gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jim/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It explains it clearly.